# Pytorch - Token embeddings using Character level LSTM

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, lstm

I'm trying to train a neural network that classifies a sequence of words. Based on a paper I'm trying to replicate, I'd need to have both token-level embeddings and character-level embeddings of tokens.

For example, take this sentence:

```
The shop is open
```

I need 2 embeddings - one is the normal `nn.Embedding` layer for the token-level embedding (very simplified!):

```
[The, shop, is, open] -> nn.Embedding -> [4,3,7,2]
```

the other is a BiLSTM embedding on the character-level:

```
[[T,h,e], [s,h,o,p], [i,s], [o,p,e,n]] -> nn.LSTM -> [9,10,23,5]
```

Both of them produce word-level embeddings but on a different scale. I tried working out how to do this in PyTorch but I can't seem to do it. The only time I can do them both at the same time is if I pass the characters as one long sequence (`[t,h,e,s,h,o,p,i,s,o,p,e,n]`), but that will only produce one embedding.

If anyone could help that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> The only time I can do them both at the same time is if I pass the characters as one long sequence ([t,h,e,s,h,o,p,i,s,o,p,e,n])

Essentially, what you have to do is:

1. Split sentences into words (each sentence has (or will have) it's respective `nn.Embedding`)
2. Split each word into single letters (essentially adding another dimension)

### About second point

Compare word-level embeddings:

> [The, shop, is, open]

This is single example, let's assume each word is encoded with `300` dimensional vector. So you get shape of `(1, 4, 300)` (batch goes first, also padding as per usual with RNNs is needed). **This data can go directly to some RNN or similar "text" models**.

> [[T,h,e], [s,h,o,p], [i,s], [o,p,e,n]]

In this case, we would have data of shape (assuming `50` dimensional vector for single letter) `(1, 4, 4, 50)`. **Please notice I have padded to the longest word based on length!**

Such input cannot go into `RNN`s for obvious reasons (it's `4D` instead of `3D` as required). But one can notice, that each word can be treated independently (as different sample), hence we can go for shape `(4, 4, 50)` (transpose is needed), where zeroth dimension corresponds to single words, first to letters contained in that word and last is vector dimensionality.

#### For batches of data

In general, for word-level encoding it is pretty simple, as you always have `(batch, timesteps, embedding)`.

**For character level**, you should form your data into vector of shape `(batch, word_timesteps, character_timesteps, embedding)`, which has to be transformed into `(batch * word_timesteps, character_timesteps, embedding)`.

**This requires some fun with padding and the size of batch grows really fast so data splitting might be needed**.

#### Output from character level LSTM

You should get (`batch * word_timesteps, network_embedding)` as output (**remember to take last timestep from each word!**). In our case it would be `(4, 50)`.

Given that, you can `reshape` this matrix into `(batch, timesteps, dimension)` (`(1, 4, 50)` in our case).

Finally, you can **concatenate** this embedding with word-level embedding **across last dimension** to get `(1, 4, 350)` output matrix in total. You can pass this into another `RNN` layer or however you wish to proceed

### Additional points

If you wish to keep information between words for character-level embedding, you would have to pass `hidden_state` to `N` elements in batch (where `N` is the number of words in sentence). That might it a little harder, but should be doable, just remember LSTM has effective capacity of `100`-`1000` AFAIK and with long sentences you can easily surpass this number of letters.